# Unicorn 3 throwing tons of errors (Rails 3.0.3, Unicorn 3.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I just tried to upgrade to Unicorn 3.0. I changed my Gemfile and did a bundle install. When restarting my Unicorn I got tons of errors beginning with:

```
Unhandled listen loop exception #<Errno::ENOSYS: Function not implemented - accept>.
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/unicorn-3.0.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:593:in `kgio_tryaccept'
```

I’m on Ubuntu 10.04.

And, can anyone explain to me why the heck I can’t use an older version of a Gem than the most recent installed? After getting the errors above I just changed the version number of Unicorn in my Gemfile to 1.1.4. But this didn’t solve the problem, Ruby told me that

```
You have already activated unicorn 3.0.0, but your Gemfile requires unicorn 1.1.4. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Do I really have to?

Thanks in advance for your help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is the one which takes care of loading the gems with the right versions. To make your server use `unicorn 1.1.4` change your `Gemfile` to point to that version of unicorn, run `bundle install` and uninstall `unicorn v3 gem` from your server.

Comment: Do I really have to? Then there seems no possibility other than RVM to operate Rails 2 and Rails 3 apps on the same machine, right?

Comment: AFAIK you can deploy rails2 and rails3 on the same machine, if you don't install the *gems* on the *server*. Use `bundle install --deployment` to install all the required gems, this installs them in a `bundle` folder under the root of your app. [Checkout Bundler Deployment for more info](http://gembundler.com/deploying.html)